# OpenLayers ->Points on the map are flashing on and off constantly. Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have edited Open Layer's "**Icon Symbolizer**"([https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html]) example for my case and latest code is different until layer definition part(line 35 on example code). Rest of the code will be same with the example.

Question is: When I put too much different colors with different features I get flashing points instead of showing all points constantly. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Any help on this is appreciated...

```
function getRandForCoordinates(from, to, fixed) {
  return (Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed) * 1;
}

function GetVectors() {
  let icons = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 850; i++) {
    
    icons[i] = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([getRandForCoordinates(-180, 180, 3)*500, getRandForCoordinates(-180, 180, 3)*5000]),
      name: 'Null Island',
      population: 4000,
      rainfall: 500,
    });
  }

  return new VectorSource({
    features: icons,
  });
}

function StyleBuilder() {
  var MyColor =
    'rgba(' +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) +
    ',' +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) +
    ',' +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) +
    ',' +
    1 +
    ')';
  return new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      color: MyColor,
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
      src: 'data/icon.png',
    }),
  });

}

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: GetVectors(),
  style: StyleBuilder,
});
```

1. I tried to give only one color and it was working as expected however I will need multiple colors.
2. I have tried to give style on feature definition. It gave me same result. Like in this function:

```
function GetVectors() {
  let icons = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 850; i++) {
    
    icons[i] = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)*500, getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)*5000]),
      name: 'Null Island',
      population: 4000,
      rainfall: 500,
    });

    icons[i].setStyle(StyleBuilder);
  }

  return icons;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a function as a style recalculates the style each time the feature is rendered.

If you set the style with the result of the function it is only called once for each feature

```
function GetVectors() {
  let icons = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 850; i++) {
    
    icons[i] = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)*500, getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)*5000]),
      name: 'Null Island',
      population: 4000,
      rainfall: 500,
    });

    icons[i].setStyle(StyleBuilder());
  }

  return icons;
}
```